# Dynamically change text on Twitter Bootstrap button whilst preserving icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I use javascript/jquery to change the text on a button in Twitter Bootstrap *without destroying the icon*?

So, this is my static markup:

```
<a class="btn" id="myButton" onclick="doSomething()"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Do it...</a>
```

I am able to change the icon, like this:

```
$('#myButton i:first-child').attr('class','icon icon-remove');
```

Which is fine, but for the love of all that is good I cannot find a way to set the button text without then wiping out the icon. Eg. if I do this:

```
$('#myButton').text('Some Remove Text');
```

I lose the icon element, so how can I access *just the text* and edit that, whilst preserving any child elements?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can wrap the content in a span element and then just find it in the context of your anchor.

```
$('#myButton span').text('Some Remove Text');
```

Also you can use $('#myButton i:first') instead of $('#myButton i:first-child') or even

```
$('#myButton i') or $('#myButton > i') which would be shorter.
```